# How to set Relogin on JWT expire MERN?

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt, authorization

I am facing an issue, my app is getting crashed with  JWT Token Expired Error. I have changed the secret key also but still same issue I am facing.

Here is the code :

Mddleware:

```
const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    const isCustomAuth = token?.length < 500;
    if (!token) 
    {return res.status(401).json({ message: "No token provided" });}
    let decodedData; 
    if(token && isCustomAuth){
    decodedData= verifyToken(token);
    req.userId = decodedData?.id;
    }
    else{
      decodedData = jwt.decode(token);
      console.log(decodedData + "decoded token");
      req.userId = decodedData?.sub;
    }
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(403).json({ message: "Token is not valid" });
    throw Error();
  }
};
```

Token verification

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

const secret = process.env.SECRET;

export const generateToken = (data) => {
    try {
        return jwt.sign({ email: data.email, id: data._id }, secret , { expiresIn: "24h" });
    } catch(e) {
        throw new Error(e)
    }
}

export const verifyToken = (token) => {
    try {
        return jwt.verify(token, secret);
    } catch(e) {
        throw new Error(e)
    }
}
```

The app is getting crashed saying jwt expired error. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely your `catch` statement:

```js
const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    // ...
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(403).json({ message: "Token is not valid" });
    throw Error(); // <--- Remove this. Don't throw in a middleware, an error response is enough
  }
};
```

By the way, there is another opportunity to improve. The catch below does nothing and is even wrong (you are passing an error instance to another Error), so I suggest you remove the try-catch altogether, or just return some nullish value there.

```js
export const verifyToken = (token) => {
    try {
        return jwt.verify(token, secret);
    } catch(e) {
        throw new Error(e) // <---- You are catching only to re-throw another error, not to mention this is a wrong way to create an error.
    }
}
```

This should be

```js
export const verifyToken = (token) => {
    return jwt.verify(token, secret);
}
```

or this, then handle the null value inside your middleware

```js
export const verifyToken = (token) => {
    try {
        return jwt.verify(token, secret);
    } catch(e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its throwing an error jwt malformed. @Thanh Son Nguyen. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

We use the jwt for authentication so that user don't need to login again and again.


**We do the following things in jwt authentication.**

- Generate the token at backend with expiry
- Store the token in localStorage at browser.

Now whenever the request is made from frontend, it also embody the token in request headers as Authorization.

> Indeed the time will come when the token will expire?
>
> Now what to do?

> So simple answer is that delete the token from localStorage.

Now you have got the answer for the first question. 
Now you have to move to the second question.

How to do it?

For that you have to look at the documentation of library which you are using for making request.
I am just giving the solution for axios. From here you will get some idea.

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
    if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
      // remove the token from localStorage
      localStorage.removeItem('token')
      window.location.href = '/login';
    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```